# Is there any way we can mask a part of log-event containing sensitive information at the logstash end?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, elk

I have some log events that I don't wanna show completely as they may contain some sensitive pieces of information, Is there any way I can mask just the sensitive part of the log keeping the rest of the logs as it is by providing the occurrence pattern via logstash?

For instance, I have below log event as a document:

```
"message" : "curl -u username:password http://example.com"
```

I want this to be stored as :

```
"message" : "curl -u XXXX:XXXX http://example.com"
```

Currently, I am dropping the event completely using `logstash drop {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this use mutate+gsub

```
mutate { gsub => [ "message", "-u [a-zA-Z0-9._-]+:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+ ", "-u XXXX:XXXX " ] }
```

For a more general discussion of anonymisation and pseudonymisation see the [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/gdpr-personal-data-pseudonymization-part-1) about GDPR.

Comment: This serves my purpose and thanks for the blogpost link.